# Laravel Php artisan migrate Error

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

What I need was to connect my new project into an old database which i used earlier project. It is must. So that I have created data model

**attendance.php**

```
class attendance extends Model
{
     protected $table = "attendance";
     protected $fillable = ['id',

    'trainee_id',
    'name',
    'time'
    ];
}
```

Then the migration called **create_attendance_table**

```
Schema::create('attendance', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('trainee_id');
            $table->strind('name');
            $table->string('time');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

As well as here is the `.env`

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:aMklPOtN0cQEm2OiaeFpBaw75ghPLTxvj8Yx7PrQ8Gc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=Training_Management
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

This is the error I'm getting.

[image]

Comment: If you have solved your problem, then please close the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have syntax error in the migration file.

So, change

```
        $table->strind('name');
```

to

```
        $table->string('name');
```

Comment: Thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

In you migration file create_attendance_table you need to change

`$table->strind('name');`

to

`$table->string('name');`

Answer (score 0):

change `$table->strind('name');` to `$table->string('name');`